# Regex to select one or multiple words after brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to select a word after brackets using RegEx and JS:

I have a dictionary of tags:

`Tags= ['Tag1', 'Tag2', 'Tag3', 'Tag4', 'Tag5']`

I have a database request that provides me with a string. I need to pick certain values from the string using Regex with the following conditions:

1. I would like to pick the words (including ä,ë,ü,ö) that come immediately after [X] (the letter X between brackets), but NOT the words that come after:

   - [UnRelatedTag][X]sunset[Y]beach[Tag1][UnrelatedTag]a[UnrelatedTag][UnrelatedTag][UnrelatedTag]

     - Expected output: sunset
2. I would like to pick the word OR the words (including ä,ë,ü,ö) that come after one of the tags in my dictionary variable, even if there are other brackets in between:

- [UnRelatedTag][X]sunset[Y]beach[Tag1][UnrelatedTag]a[UnrelatedTag][UnrelatedTag][UnrelatedTag]
  -- Expected output: a
- [UnRelatedTag][X]sunset[Y]beach[Tag1][UnrelatedTag]paintball[UnrelatedTag][UnrelatedTag][UnrelatedTag]
  -- Expected output: paintball
- [UnRelatedTag][X]sunset[Y]beach[Tag1][UnrelatedTag]paintball[UnrelatedTag][UnrelatedTag][UnrelatedTag]yacht
  -- Expected output: paintball, yacht.
- [UnRelatedTag][X]sunset[Y]beach[Tag1]snowball
  -- Expected output: snowball.

3. The final result is to be used in JS, to concat the word after [X] and the single/multiple words after [Tag] into one string.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You can edit your question write a stack snippet that sets up the exact text that is to be processed.  JavaScript might be less ambiguous than your verbal description.  It sounds like if you have `[a]one[b]two[c]three` as input that you want to be able to pass in `b` as an argument and get `two` as a result.  You're defining some _prefix-tag-like_ syntax using square brackets.  My example would have JavaScript object structure similar to `{ "a": "one", "b": "two", "c": "three" }` Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are example input strings and code to extract the words based on your spec:

```js
const strings = [
  '[UnRelatedTag][X]sunset[Y]beach[Tag1][UnrelatedTag]a[UnrelatedTag][UnrelatedTag][UnrelatedTag]',
  '[UnRelatedTag][X]sunset[Y]beach[Tag1][UnrelatedTag]paintball[UnrelatedTag][UnrelatedTag][UnrelatedTag]',
  '[UnRelatedTag][X]sunset[Y]beach[Tag1][UnrelatedTag]paintball[UnrelatedTag][UnrelatedTag][UnrelatedTag]yacht',
  '[UnRelatedTag][X]sunset[Y]beach[Tag1]snowball'
];
const tags = ['Tag1', 'Tag2', 'Tag3', 'Tag4', 'Tag5'];
const regex1 = new RegExp('\\[X\\]([\\wäëüö]+).*?\\[(?:' + tags.join('|') + ')\\](.*)', 'i');
const regex2 = /\[[^\]]*\]/;

strings.forEach(str => {
  let result = [];
  let m = str.match(regex1);
  if(m) {
    result.push(m[1]);
    m[2].split(regex2).filter(Boolean).forEach(s => {
      result.push(s);
    });
  }
  console.log(str + '\n ==> ' + result.join(', '));
});
```

Output:

```
[UnRelatedTag][X]sunset[Y]beach[Tag1][UnrelatedTag]a[UnrelatedTag][UnrelatedTag][UnrelatedTag]
 ==> sunset, a
[UnRelatedTag][X]sunset[Y]beach[Tag1][UnrelatedTag]paintball[UnrelatedTag][UnrelatedTag][UnrelatedTag]
 ==> sunset, paintball
[UnRelatedTag][X]sunset[Y]beach[Tag1][UnrelatedTag]paintball[UnrelatedTag][UnrelatedTag][UnrelatedTag]yacht
 ==> sunset, paintball, yacht
[UnRelatedTag][X]sunset[Y]beach[Tag1]snowball
 ==> sunset, snowball
```

Explanation:

- `regex1`:

  - built dynamically based on your tag array
  - two capture groups, one for the word after tag `[X]`, one for all text that follows a tag in your tag array
- if there is a match:

  - the first capture group is added to the result
  - the second capture group:

    - is split on tag pattern `[`...`]`
    - the `.filter(Boolean)` filters out empty strings
    - you could filter further by word pattern of interest
    - each split item is added to the result
- join the result array with any delimiter you want, here `,`

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can take the left boundary (.*?) right boundary

Example :  [X]](.*?)\W[Y] : For Sunset

you can use https://regex101.com/ which will guide too.